# Unix script to filter files

Tags: shell, unix

I have to write a unix script and I am really not familiar with it and need help.

I have a root directory, inside it I have a lot of other directories.
Each directory contains `txt files`.
I have to go through all the directories and all the files:

- If a file contains the phrase `"file information"` I want to keep the
  file.
- If the file does not contain it, I want to delete the file.
- Then, If all the files of a directory have been deleted, and the
  directory is empty, I want to delete the directory.

How can I write a script like that?

Thanks

Comment: Which command finds files or directories?  Which command finds words in files?  What option makes the command list file names?  The `rmdir` command is noisy but doesn't remove non-empty directories.  If you sort a list of directories in reverse order, you can feed the list to `rmdir` and it will deal with all empty directories safely.  How do you redirect standard error so it doesn't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to delete all files that contains "STRING":

```
rm -rf $(find . -type f -exec grep -l 'STRING' {} \;)
```

and to delete all empry directories:

```
find . -empty -type d -delete
```

**UPDATE**

from `man grep`:

> **-L, --files-without-match**
>
> ```
>           Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally  have  been  printed.
>           The scanning will stop on the first match.
> ```
>
> **-l, --files-with-matches**
>
> ```
>           Suppress  normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The
>           scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: thanks.
How do I delete all the file that does not contain "STRING"?

Comment: change `-l` option to `-L`

Comment: thanks. find works fine, but it does not delete. it writes "Illegal variable name".
Maybe it is because the file name is try.txt, and find returns ./try.txt  ?